# Need to get the first image link with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, urllib

I need to get the link of the first photo from the link "https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/9127382" using Python.

I am testing with the BeautifullSoup library but there is no way to get it. From what I see, the image is not in JPG or PNG format, therefore, it does not detect it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen('https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/9127382')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.png')})
for image in images: 
    print(image['src']+'\n')
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Full Loop Code: ("s" contains many ships data (IMO, date, shipname...))

```
def create_geojson_features(s):

features = []

for _, row in s.iterrows():
    vessel_id = row['IMO']

    data = {
        "templates[]": [
            "modal_validation_errors:0",
            "modal_email_verificate:0",
            "r_vessel_types_multi:0",
            "r_positions_single:0",
            "vessel_profile:0",
        ],
        "request[0][module]": "ships",
        "request[0][action]": "list",
        "request[0][id]": "0",
        "request[0][data][0][name]": "imo",
        "request[0][data][0][value]": vessel_id,
        "request[0][sort]": "",
        "request[0][limit]": "1",
        "request[0][stamp]": "0",
        "request[1][module]": "top_stat",
        "request[1][action]": "list",
        "request[1][id]": "0",
        "request[1][data]": "",
        "request[1][sort]": "",
        "request[1][limit]": "",
        "request[1][stamp]": "0",
        "dictionary[]": ["countrys:0", "vessel_types:0", "positions:0"],
    }
    
    data = requests.post("https://www.balticshipping.com/", data=data).json()
    image = data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"][0]["file"]
    print(image)
    feature = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type':'Point',
            'coordinates':[row['lon'],row['lat']]
        },
        'properties': {
            'time': pd.to_datetime(row['date']).__str__(),
            'popup': "<img src=" + image.__str__() + " width = '250' height='200'/>"+'<br>'+'<br>'+'Shipname: '+row['shipname'].__str__() +'<br>'+ 'MMSI: '+row['mmsi'].__str__() +'<br>' + 'Group: '+row['group'].__str__() +'<br>''Speed: '+row['speed'].__str__()+' knots',
            'style': {'color' : ''},
            'icon': 'circle',
            'iconstyle':{
                'fillColor': row['fillColor'],
                'fillOpacity': 0.8,
                'radius': 5
            }
        }
    }
    features.append(feature)
return features
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see are loaded via Ajax from external source. You can use this example how to get the picture URLs:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/9127382"
vessel_id = url.split("/")[-1]

data = {
    "templates[]": [
        "modal_validation_errors:0",
        "modal_email_verificate:0",
        "r_vessel_types_multi:0",
        "r_positions_single:0",
        "vessel_profile:0",
    ],
    "request[0][module]": "ships",
    "request[0][action]": "list",
    "request[0][id]": "0",
    "request[0][data][0][name]": "imo",
    "request[0][data][0][value]": vessel_id,
    "request[0][sort]": "",
    "request[0][limit]": "1",
    "request[0][stamp]": "0",
    "request[1][module]": "top_stat",
    "request[1][action]": "list",
    "request[1][id]": "0",
    "request[1][data]": "",
    "request[1][sort]": "",
    "request[1][limit]": "",
    "request[1][stamp]": "0",
    "dictionary[]": ["countrys:0", "vessel_types:0", "positions:0"],
}

data = requests.post("https://www.balticshipping.com/", data=data).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for g in data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"]:
    print(g["file"])
```

Prints:

```
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2948097
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2864147
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2830344
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2674783
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2521379
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2083722
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2083721
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1599301
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1464102
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1464099
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1464093
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1464089
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=1110349
https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=433106
```

Comment: Works fine!! But how can I acces to the first link `first_photo = g["file"][0]` ?

Comment: @ÒscarFuentes To get first URL, you can `first = data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"][0]["file"]`

Comment: And It's possible to use the link of the photo as a png or jpg link? I'm doing a map with Folium, so i want to show the photo on the popup. Thanks for all!

Comment: @ÒscarFuentes The image is already JPG, so `<img src="https://photos.marinetraffic.com/ais/showphoto.aspx?photoid=2948097" />` should work.

Comment: Right, it works! Sorry to ask you another question, the code goes inside a loop, and the link changes (different ships). When looking for all the photos of each link, it takes a long time. Is there any way I can only search for the first photo in the link and stop searching?

Comment: On Windows the code works fine, but I need to run it on a Linux and I'm reciving ``image = data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"][0]["file"]
IndexError: list index out of range``

Comment: @ÒscarFuentes Do `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` and verify if the data is there. Maybe you've received CAPTCHA page.

Comment: Printed many lines of code, the end is: ``"prices": {
        "unlock": 5
    }
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AIS_map.py", line 180, in <module>
    start_geojson = create_geojson_features(s_copy)
  File "AIS_map.py", line 77, in create_geojson_features
    image = data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"][0]["file"]
IndexError: list index out of range``

Comment: I think the problem is there is an IMO number that when looking for it on the web "https://www.balticshipping.com/vessel/imo/" does not appear any image and causes the error to appear. Is there a way that if it doesn't find photos, it will go to the next one? I put the code of the loop in the first message in case it helps.

By the way, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: SOLVED!! ``try:
    image = data["data"]["request"][0]["ships"][0]["data"]["gallery"][0]["file"]
except IndexError:
    image= 'null'``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231261/discussion-between-oscar-fuentes-and-andrej-kesely).